# How to solve error "bundler could not find compatible version for gem X"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rubygems

I'm trying to setup docker for my project. I have tried installing actionpack 5.0.2, but it did not do me any good. I am following a tutorial on how to setup, so I reckon there are version issues. When I run docker-compose up, this is what I get:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
  rails (~> 5.0.2) ruby depends on
  actionpack (= 5.0.2) ruby

  actionpack (>= 5.1.1, ~> 5.1) ruby
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
gem 'devise'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', :platforms => :ruby

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'unicorn', '~> 4.9'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.3'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'redis-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'actionpack', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.1'
```

EDIT: Tried removing the gem actionpack entirely from the gemfile, caused new issues on docker-compose up:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.2) ruby depends on
      actioncable (= 5.0.2) ruby depends on
        actionpack (= 5.0.2) ruby

    rails (~> 5.0.2) ruby depends on
      actioncable (= 5.0.2) ruby depends on
        actionpack (= 5.0.2) ruby

    rails (~> 5.0.2) ruby depends on
      actioncable (= 5.0.2) ruby depends on
        actionpack (= 5.0.2) ruby

    rails (~> 5.0.2) ruby depends on
      actioncable (= 5.0.2) ruby depends on
        actionpack (= 5.0.2) ruby

    redis-rails (~> 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      redis-actionpack (~> 4) ruby depends on
        actionpack (~> 4) ruby
ERROR: Service 'drkiq' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 6
```

Comment: Try to `bundle update` and then `bundle install`

Comment: ^^ No. The error message is quite self-explanatory; you have a dependency mis-match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines in your `Gemfile` are causing a dependency conflict:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
gem 'actionpack', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.1'
```

`~> 5.0.2` means "Greater than `5.0.2` and less than `5.1.0`".

`'~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.1'` means "Greater than `5.1.1` and less than `6.0.0`.".

Hence there is a conflict, and Bundler fails to resolve. You need to either upgrade `rails` or downgrade`actionpack`.

The easiest solution is probably to just **remove `actionpack` from the `Gemfile`**, since you don't really need to specify it at all. `actionpack` is a dependency of `rails`, so it will be installed regardless.

I would also suggest that you **remove the `'~> 5.0.2'` version constraint on `rails`**, unless you have a good reason to lock down the version number.

**Update regarding your second error:**

This error is very similar to the above; it's quite self-explanatory.

```
rails (~> 5.0.2) ruby depends on
  [...]
    actionpack (= 5.0.2) ruby

redis-rails (~> 4.0.0) ruby depends on
  [...]
    actionpack (~> 4) ruby
```

Just like above, you have one gem that depends on actionpack version `v4.x.x`, and another gem that depends on actionpack `v5.0.2`.

You need to somehow update/loosen the version constraint in your `Gemfile`. For example, you could write:

```
gem 'redis-rails', '~> 5.0'
```

Comment: I removed the line, but it gave me new dependency issues. I pasted it in @RichardAE's answer.

Comment: Please [update the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44198818/edit) (with proper formatting), so we can all see it in full. The error should hopefully be quite self-explanatory, however.

Comment: Your edit worked. I did not realize it was showing a conflict between two gems depending on different versions of the same one.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified to use actionpack greater or equal to 5.1:

```
gem 'actionpack', '~> 5.1', '>= 5.1.1'
```

However Rails 5.0.2 is specifically locked to actionpack 5.0.2. Remove the line above from your Gemfile, it's superfluous.

Comment: I did so, and tried to compose again. Output:

In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.2) ruby depends on
      actioncable (= 5.0.2) ruby depends on
        actionpack (= 5.0.2) ruby

    rails (~> 5.0.2) ruby depends on
      actioncable (= 5.0.2) ruby depends on
        actionpack (= 5.0.2) ruby

    rails (~> 5.0.2) ruby depends on
      actioncable (= 5.0.2) ruby depends on
        actionpack (= 5.0.2) ruby

    rails (~> 5.0.2) ruby depends on
      actioncable (= 5.0.2) ruby depends on
        actionpack (= 5.0.2) ruby

Comment: Why aren't you using the latest version of Rails out of interest?

Comment: No real reason. It's just the version that was already there when I generated the project.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have a dependency problem.

In your Gemfile try using:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'actionpack', '~> 5.1.1'
```